# Can not access php inside laravel assets folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have problems with loading some files from laravel `assets` folder.
I am using `laravel 4.2`.
This works fine in my local environment but not works on shared hosting. This used to work but somehow stops working.
I have made tester.php and put it into `assets` folder and I can not access it. Here is a url which returns 404: http://example.com/assets/vendors/kcfinder-2.54/tester.php.
The whole problem starts when I have noticed that I have problem with `kcfinder`.

This is inside `ckeditor` `config.js`:

```
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/assets/vendors/kcfinder-2.54/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/assets/vendors/kcfinder-2.54/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
```

and this not works. Even if I try to acces it directkly using: http://example.com/assets/vendors/kcfinder-2.54/tester.php
 I can not open this url. Gives me 404.

But then I have made assets2 folder and all start to work. So I have changed `config.js` to

```
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/assets2/vendors/kcfinder-2.54/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/assets2/vendors/kcfinder-2.54/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
```

and kcfinder starts to work.Also I can open directly url http://example.com/assets2/vendors/kcfinder-2.54/tester.php

So what is the best way to detect why laravel is not serving php from assets folder?

Comment: Please show the code snippet where you are including the asset.

Comment: I have edited question with relevant info.